# How to prevent Spring router functions from adding charset to content-type?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

When using Spring servlet router functions the Content-Type header is changed by the framework.
Spring adds `charset=UTF-8` to it.

Is there a way to make sure that the original Content-Type header is not changed?

You can reproduce this with a simple router function:

```kotlin
@Configuration
class RouterPoC(
    private val handlerPoc: HandlerPoc
) {
    @Bean
    fun demo() = router {
        GET("/router", handlerPoc::checkContentType)
    }
}

@Component
class HandlerPoc {

    private val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this::class.java)

    fun checkContentType(request: ServerRequest): ServerResponse {
        val contentType = request.headers().contentTypeOrNull()!!.toString()
        logger.info(contentType)
        check(!contentType.endsWith("charset=UTF-8"))
        return ServerResponse.ok().build()
    }
}
```

You can find this demo code here: https://github.com/detached/spring-charset-poc/

And sending a request with

```
curl -X GET -H 'Content-Type: application/json' localhost:8080/router
```

The resulting Content-Type is `application/json;charset=UTF-8`. I would expect that the header stays untouched like `application/json`.

When I see it correctly, the charset is added by [DefaultServerRequest](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/d50ec68ad7bbbc195353e1ba59e2a613bc80013a/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/function/DefaultServerRequest.java#L104) parsing the servletRequest with ServletServerHttpRequest. The [getHeaders()](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/http/server/ServletServerHttpRequest.java#L168) function adds then the charset to the header.

Setting `server.servlet.encoding.force=false` has no effect.

`RestController` behaves differently, there no charset is added to the header value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked this question in the spring-framework github issues
(https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/31477)
And got a really nice answer:

The solution for me is to use the Content-Type from `ServerRequest.servletRequest`.

This works now:

```
fun checkContentType(request: ServerRequest): ServerResponse {
        val contentType = request.servletRequest().contentType
        check(!contentType.endsWith("charset=UTF-8"))
        return ServerResponse.ok().build()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can make CharacterEncodingFilter not work

```
@Component
public class MyBeanPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor{
    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        if(bean instanceof CharacterEncodingFilter filter){
            filter.setEncoding(null);
        }
        return bean;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
This solution certainly works (the header is not modified any more) but it feels like a hack to change the state of this bean.

Comment: And I am not sure which other implication this solution has. The [CharacterEncodingFilter](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/filter/CharacterEncodingFilter.java#L195) sets the character encoding of the [Request](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/10.1.x/java/org/apache/coyote/Request.java#L425).